# How to delete elements with react? (Basic React query)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a total newbie with React and I was trying to build an app with React, but after many hours of trying, I couldn't figure out why the elements that I want to delete `onClick` aren't getting deleted.

There are 2 similar posts on this, they say that you would need to use independent keys for every element. I tried to do that, I even created a different variable and increment it after every use. **It just deletes the top element of the list.**

**How it works -** 1) I have an array which is stored with some names `channels`, and I get data with that names and save that data into another array `renderAll`.

2) After that I filter those on how I want to render them, and then I render them with a function `renderCards()`. It also renders a button which if clicked, should delete the channel from the `channel` array and the respective data from the `renderAll` array

3) It also have a input field from which you can add more channels.

**What doesn't work** - The delete button deletes the top element instead of the element which is clicked.

[I have the app running without the delete functionality](http://lord-lavios.github.io/Who-s-Streaming/)

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            status: 2
        }
    },
    changeStatus(i) {
        this.setState({
            status: i
        });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header><h1>Twitch Streamers</h1></header>
                <Tabs status = {this.changeStatus} />
                <Cards status = {this.state.status} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


const Cards = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            renderAll: [],
            check: this.props.status,
            channels:  ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx","meteos","RobotCaleb","noobs2ninjas","brunofin","comster404","cretetion","sheevergaming","TR7K","OgamingSC2","ESL_SC2"]
        };
    }, //AJAX REQUEST FUNCTION
    getData(last) {
        if(last === undefined) {
            for(let i =0; i<this.state.channels.length;i++) {
                let channel = this.state.channels[i];
                $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel, (data) => {
                    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channel, (logo) => {
                        if(data.hasOwnProperty(status) === false) {
                            if(data.stream === null) {
                                this.setState({
                                    renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: channel, url: `https://www.twitch.tv/${channel}`, status: 'offline', logo: logo.logo}])
                                });
                            } else {
                                this.setState({
                                    renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: data.stream.channel.name, url: `https://www.twitch.tv/${channel}`, current: data.stream.channel.game + ' - ' + data.stream.channel.status, status: 'online', logo: logo.logo}])
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })  
                .fail((jqxhr) => {
                    this.setState({
                        renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: channel, status: 'closed'}])
                    });
                });
            }
        } else {
            let channel = this.state.channels[this.state.channels.length - 1];
            $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel, (data) => {
                $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channel, (logo) => {
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty(status) === false) {
                        if(data.stream === null) {
                            this.setState({
                                renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: channel, url: `https://www.twitch.tv/${channel}`, status: 'offline', logo: logo.logo}])
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.setState({
                                renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: data.stream.channel.name, url: `https://www.twitch.tv/${channel}`, current: data.stream.channel.game + ' - ' + data.stream.channel.status, status: 'online', logo: logo.logo}])
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            })  
            .fail((jqxhr) => {
                this.setState({
                    renderAll: this.state.renderAll.concat([{channel: channel, status: 'closed'}])
                });
            });
        }
    },
    componentWillMount() {
        this.getData();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(prop) {
        this.setState({
            check: prop
        });
    }, //DELETE FUNCTION THAT DOESN'T WORK
    delete(index) {
        let newArr = this.state.channels.slice();
        let newArrSecond = this.state.renderAll.slice();

        newArr.splice(index, 1);
        newArrSecond.splice(index, 1);

        this.setState({
            channels: newArr,
            renderAll: newArrSecond
        });
    }, //RENDER CARDS FUNCTION
    renderCards(i) {
        if(i === 0 || i.status === 0) {
            let cards = this.state.renderAll.map((item, i) => {
                if(item.status === 'online') {
                    return <div className="online cards" key={i}><img src={item.logo} width="30px" height="30px" /><a target="_blank" href={item.url}><h3>{item.channel}</h3></a><button className="cross" onClick={this.delete}>✕</button><p>{item.current}</p></div>
                }
            });
            return (
                cards
            )
        } else if(i === 1 || i.status === 1) {
            let cards = this.state.renderAll.map((item, i) => {
                if(item.status === 'offline') {
                    return <div className="offline cards" key={i}><img src={item.logo} width="30px" height="30px"/><a target="_blank" href={item.url}><h3>{item.channel}</h3></a><button className="cross" onClick={this.delete}>✕</button><p>Channel is offline</p></div>
                }
            });
            return (
                cards
            )
        } else if(i === 2 || i.status === 2) {
            let cards = this.state.renderAll.map((item, i) => {
                if(item.status === 'offline') {
                    return <div className="offline cards" key={i}><img src={item.logo} width="30px" height="30px" /><a target="_blank" href={item.url}><h3>{item.channel}</h3></a><button className="cross" onClick={this.delete}>✕</button><p>Channel is offline</p></div>
                } else if(item.status === 'online') {
                    return <div className="online cards" key={i}><img src={item.logo} width="30px" height="30px" /><a target="_blank" href={item.url}><h3>{item.channel}</h3></a><button className="cross" onClick={this.delete}>✕</button><p>{item.current}</p></div>
                } else {
                    return <div className="closed cards" key={i}><h3>{item.channel}</h3><p>Account Closed</p></div>
                }
            });
            return (
                cards
            )
        }
    },
    newChannel(i) {
        if(i.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState({channels: this.state.channels.concat([i.target.value])}, function() {
                this.getData(1);
            });
        }
    },
    leave(i) {
        i.target.value = '';
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="cards-inside">
                <input type='text' placeholder="+ Channel" onKeyDown={this.newChannel} onBlur={this.leave}/>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                    {this.renderCards(this.state.check)}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>  
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container-second"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index` is always 0, because you do not pass it when you call `delete`.

Therefore it always deletes top element.

Inside the JSX bit where you render your X, you should do:

```
onClick={this.delete.bind(this, i)}
```

Or try

```
OnClick={() => {this.delete(i)} }
```

to pass the index of the card clicked.

Comment: It doesn't work and it also gives an extra error,  "Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See Cards"

Comment: I am sure the cause of the problem is that you need to pass the index. I updated answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In React, you don't really want to "delete" nodes like you'd do with jQuery.

Let's say you have a list of names in your initial state:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    names: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Git', 'Get']
  };
  [...]
}
```

In your `render()` method, you are rendering them inside a `ul`:

```
render() {
  const names = this.state.names.map(name => {
    return <li key={name} onClick={this.remove.bind(this, name)}>{name}</li>;
  });
  return <ul>{names}</ul>;
}
```

In your `remove()` method you will have:

```
remove(name) {
  this.setState({
    names: this.state.names.filter(cur => cur !== name)
  });
}
```

Now, every time you click on a name to remove it, you are removing the name from the names list, the component renders itself again, and the removed name will be removed from the DOM.

Working example:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/MeWpzm?editors=0010